# AG Grid clip long text in cell and show all on click

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a tall row like this

[image: picture]

and I managed to display It like this

[image: that]

I also want to display it like on the first picture after the dots click.
To achieve it I made a custom cell renderer it's changing the inner HTML content of a cell. And my problem is that after change content to long row has the same height so I cant see full text.
Is there any method to rerender rows or the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set these two property on the column which is getting expanded.

```
wrapText: true,
autoHeight: true,
```

if this behavior is needed on all column or you are not sure better define these under

```
defaultColDef: {
    ....    
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 110,
    editable: true,
    resizable: true,
    wrapText: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    ...
  },
```

then call `resetRowHeights();` on `cellValueChanged` event.

```
onCellValueChanged : function(params){ params.api.resetRowHeights();}
```